# Как найти номер и количество экранов (групп) слайдов в карусели owl carousel 2?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Добрый вечер. Помогите вывести не количество итемов в подсчете, а количество групп итемов http://prntscr.com/c40jbw, которые включают, как в данном примере 3 итема. спасибо

jsfiddle.net/vnpm1y06/153 вот пример. но этот пример считает количество бирюзовых блоков, а нужно чтобы считал количество экранов,т.е.групп этих блоков. в данном случае по 2 блока в группе prntscr.com/c40p1r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант `this.items().length` делить на количество итемов в блоке `items: 1`

скрипт

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
var items = 3;
owl.owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  items: items,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  onInitialized: function(e) {
    $('.counter').text('1 из ' + Math.ceil(this.items().length/items))
    console.log();
  }
});
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
  $('.counter').text(Math.ceil((e.item.index - 1)/items) + ' из ' + Math.ceil(e.item.count/items))
});
```

`

Comment: Общее количество item ему уже известно.

Comment: Нужны вот эти значения:
 // Provided by the navigation plugin
    var pages     = event.page.count;     // Number of pages
    var page      = event.page.index;     // Position of the current page
    var size      = event.page.size;      // Number of items per page

Comment: @Дима эти данные доступны только внутри события `changed.owl.carousel`. В методе `onInitialized` придётся использовать то что предложил @Dmitry Kondratiuk. Сохранять items в отдельную переменную не нужно, это можно получить через `this.settings.items`